# JavaScript null; placeholder vs "ready for purging"

Tags: javascript, null

Just read some material that stated 'null' in javascript can be used as a placeholder. But then it moved on to saying that 'null' can also indicate that a certain variable is ready for purging. But how does javascript know whether a variable with null is currently acting as a placeholder and not "ready for purging"... or vice versa?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Did it specifically say that ***Javascript*** considers `null` as "ready for purging"? My guess would be that that's just meant as a convention for the programmer...

Comment: What is *ready for purging* anyway? Eligible for garbage collection? That makes little sense, because when a variable is bound to `null`, it is by definition no longer bound to a collectible object.

Comment: Speculation; Could also be that once a variable that holds an object/value and then set to null its ready for GC, while as if null is being assigned to a new variable it's in a "state" mode.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, the book meant "ready for garbage collection".

Comment: @Daniel Okay, that's interesting. But I would love to read up on this particular issue. I can't seem to find anything directly related.

Comment: Then it's probably just saying that if you assign `null` to a variable **which previously held a value**, that previous value can now be garbage collected.

Comment: @Grateful, well, you could also bind the variable to `undefined` or simply issue `delete variable` to emphasize its previous content is ready to be collected (assuming no other outstanding references). `null` doesn't strike me as "special" in that respect.

Comment: If the variable previously held a reference to an object, you could assign it to literally any other value and that would allow the previous object to be garbage collected. (Assuming there are no other references to it.) Using `null` more commonly indicates that the variable in question *could* reference an object but doesn't currently do so.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi "... bind a variable to `undefined`...", wow! I am not sure about whether that's a recommended practice. I recently read that `undefined` represents an UNEXPECTED absence of value, as apposed to `null` which represents an EXPECTED absence of value. Anyway, can you provide any references for what you have claimed? I would love to be educated on this issue.

Comment: @Grateful, *I recently read that undefined represents an UNEXPECTED absence of value, as apposed to null which represents an EXPECTED absence of value.* That's a useful convention, yes, but not everybody follows it. As for references, you can definitely bind a variable to `undefined` (`var foo = undefined;`) and the `delete` operator is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thank you for the reference. But, it lead me to believe that 'delete' is a way of removing a certain property from an object... which has a different context to `null` being used to mean "no object". It is possible to assign an object property to null, but it will still remain a part of that object... simply as a property with null. Whereas if you `delete` a property, it no longer remains part of the object.

Comment: @Grateful, yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That material is a bit misleading. Both are correct, sort of, but it's not variables that are purged; it's values (objects) that are purged.

When a variable points to something, for example like this:

```
mango = "Hi there!";
```

A bit of memory is allocated to hold the 9 byte value of `"Hi there!"` (note: the amount of memory allocated is usually more than 9 bytes. It's at least 10 bytes to include either a null terminator or a byte count).

When you then assign the value `null` to it like this:

```
mango = null;
```

The string `"Hi there!"` can no longer be used by the program because it is no longer referenced by any variable (unless it is referenced by some other variable). As such, it is a candidate for garbage collection. That is what it means for something to be ready for purging.

To summarise:

1. Javascript treats `null` as a value that can be assigned to variables. It does not interpret what it means for a variable to be `null`.
2. A human programmer can use `null` as a value that means "placeholder" (note: programmers can also use it to mean "no value", the language does not care what programmers think).
3. An object/value that has no variable pointing to it can be garbage collected.
4. Setting a variable to `null` means it is no longer pointing to its previous value. That means setting variables to null can be used as a mechanism to free memory.

Comment: Nitpicking, but JavaScript's strings have been UNICODE-based since the get-go. So, `"Hi there!"` won't take 10 bytes, but 20 bytes on Windows (UCS-2) and *40 bytes* on Linux (UTF-32, with `wchar_t` being four-bytes wide).

Comment: @slebetman Just trying to digest your post, and I have a few questions as a result. Firstly, you mentioned that javascript does not interpret what it means for a variable to be null, however you then went on to say that setting a variable to null means that it is no longer pointing to its previous value. Hence javascript uses that as a mechanism to free memory! Mmmm... so it DOES interpret null to mean "ready for purging". That sounds a bit inconsistent to me. Secondly, if the programmer treats null as a placeholder, doesn't that conflict with javascript interpreting that as "free memory now"?

Comment: @Grateful: Setting a variable to null does not "mean" that it no longer points to its previous value. It IS no longer pointing to its previous value. There is no meaning to the null. The variable is merely pointing to it. In short. Setting a variable to null MEANS the variable now points to null. Nothing else. Now, there is another mechanism, that has nothing at all to do with null, wherein an object/value that is not pointed to by any variable is marked for deletion. Note that you can also free memory by assigning the variable a new value such as an empty string or `{}` or `"mango"` etc.

Comment: @Grateful: So, javascript does NOT treat null to mean "free memory now". It treats all values/objects that is not pointed to by any variable as freeable. It may or may not free immediately because deciding weather an object has no reference is not a simple thing especially when considering circular references. Also because freeing memory is sometimes slow so the interpreter may wait until it has nothing to do to free memory.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Javascript first came out long before UNICODE was finalized. I certainly remember compiling Netscape's javascript engine to use in a node.js style application and it used plain C strings. So not exactly from the get-go. Besides, HOW strings are treated is implementation dependent. It's certainly possible to implement UTF-8 (like in the TCL programming language) which would indeed take 10 bytes.

Comment: Right! Thank you guys for all the details. I think I have come away from this with a lot more insight...